# is my nginx configuration doing me any good? do i even need the proxy pass?

Tags: node.js, nginx, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi running a node server on my local network via pm2. And I'm using nginx on the raspberry pi to serve my static front end.

Does this setup even benefit from a reverse proxy server? This current configuration is working fine:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /home/pi/Documents/mysite/client/; #
        index index.html;
        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404 ;
        }
}
```

Hope this kind of question is ok, happy to provide any more code.

Comment: In your particular case nginX is just one more layer in the communication. You can simply serve everything from your Express-based Node.JS application.

Comment: But then would I need nginx to forward port 80 to node's 3000?
Or is there another way to do that?

Comment: Yes, the proper way is to tell Node to listen on port 80 instead of 3000.